# When I use tailwind and element loading,the loading spinner isnt at the center of screen,how to fix it?

Tags: vuejs2, element, tailwind-css

## My environment is

- "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.9",
- "postcss": "^7",
- "vue": "^2.6.12",
- "element-ui": "^2.15.1",
- "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
  [image]

Comment: Can you please add sandbox example of above problem?

Answer (score 0):

The tailwind will kill some styles like h1's padding etc.

if you just want to fix this tiny problem like me

You can just add a style to cover the default element-ui style for making this spinner "center" in global css file:

```
.el-loading-spinner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If anyone found a better way or why,please leave your answer, appreciate it.